# How to parse form data to work with JSON in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms

```
 var checkedValues = $('.required:checked').map(function () {
                return this.value;
            }).get();

            var arr = new Array(10);
            alert(checkedValues);
            alert("number of values in it " +checkedValues.length);
            if (checkedValues.length > 1) {

                alert("I am inside if ");
                 arr = checkedValues.split(',');

                alert("I am done with the split ");
            }
            else {
                arr = checkedValues;
                alert("No split needed ");
            }





               $.getJSON('@Url.Action("testcata", "home")' +  + '?Type=' + "@(Session["typ"])" + "&city=" + "@(Session["cit"])" + "&chkd=" + checkedValues,


            function (data) {

                           //code
                        })

In controller :
 public ActionResult testcata(string Type, int? city, int[] chkd)
    {
      //code
    }
```

I am trying to get the values of check-boxes which are checked and store them in array which are then sent to controller through json function. alert("I am done with the split") is not being shown . Please help me.

Comment: use console log instead of alert

Comment: can you show the html?

Comment: `checkedValues` is already an array. What are you trying to split?

Comment: did you know that the .map function of jquery returns an array?
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/

Comment: @onetrickpony - Then why the method in the controller taking null as a parameter for more than one selected check values ? I am having a int[] chkd parameter in the function . It shows null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/):

```
var checkedValues = $('.required:checked').serializeArray();
```

It returns an array ready for JSON, like so:

```
[
  {
    name: "a",
    value: "1"
  },
  {
    name: "b",
    value: "2"
  },
  {
    name: "c",
    value: "3"
  },
  {
    name: "d",
    value: "4"
  },
  {
    name: "e",
    value: "5"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

`split` works on string .you can use `split on  each array index` not on `whole array`.

if you really want to split array `checkedValues` then loop through this array then `use split on each index`.

like this:

```
for( var i=0; i< checkedValues.length;i++){

var arr = checkedValues[i].split(',');
// use arr for requrement.

}
```

Comment: you should rather include in your answer what needs to be changed to achieve what the OP is trying

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
// array of values
var arr = [];
$(".required")
    .on("change", function (e) {
    // `checked` `.required` elements
    var checkedValues = $(this).prop("checked");
    // `if` `checkedValues` (any `required` elements `checked`) , continue
    if (checkedValues) {
        // populate `arr` with `.required` `checked` values
        arr.push(checkedValues);
        // do stuff with `arr`
        // `console.log` values in `arr` , `arr` length
        console.log("array of values: " + arr
                    , "array of values length: " + arr.length);
    };
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/d332nfkh/

Comment: console.log is not showing any thing when I check the check-boxes and then run

Comment: Not certain what issue is , at each check of checkbox , `array of values: true array of values length: 1` , `array of values: true,true array of values length: 2` , etc. logged to `console` at jsfiddle.